# DiscordJS | Copy embed message to another chat

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I made a synchronization of a form with a discord hook and in it there are 3 reactions that an external BOT puts, inside these reactions I wanted to make that when one is selected, have a confirmation and if the confirmation is yes, the BOT sends the embed message to another embed chat as well.

The reactions are already being placed automatically, but I am not able to know how to copy the embed message to send in another chat depending on the reactions chosen in JS.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I have an embed message in a chat created by a hook, and this message created by I wanted to copy it to another chat by clicking on a reaction basically.
Like if I just moved it.

Answer (score 1):

Simply grab the content and embeds from the message, and send it somewhere else.

```js
//channel is a TextChannel instance, message is a Message instance
const { content, embeds } = message
channel.send({
  content,
  embeds
})
```

Note that `channel` is the target channel where you want to send the copied the message

Comment: ```client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.channel.id === analiseChannelID) {
        message.react(aprovada);
        message.react(nula);
        message.react(negada);
    } 
});

client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (ReactionCollector.emoji.id === aprovadasChannelID) {
// Copy the embed from analiseChannelID, paste on aprovadasChannelID and delete it on analiseChannelID    
     }
});```

I've been trying something like this, but I don't know if it's the best method and how I should copy that embed depending on the reaction